# Python SQLALCHEMY query using MID()

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database and am trying to query information using the MID() function.  In normal SQL I would use MID such as (From W3 example website)..

```
SELECT MID(City,1,4) AS ShortCity
FROM Customers;
```

Converting this to sqlalchemy has been a bit of a challenge. I am able to perform the query with pagination, but not utilizing mid. So far I have 
Original query that works..

```
   links = Item.query.filter(Item.title.like('%' +search_term +'%')).paginate(page, 10, True)
```

Converting it to doesnt work..

```
 links = Item.query.filter(func.mid(Item.title.like, 1, 3)('%' +search_term + '%')).paginate(page, 10, True)



    TypeError: 'Function' object is not callable
```

I want only x-y amount of characters from the title(string column)

Comment: i can see that you're missing a comma `,`, i.e. `func.mid(Item.title.like, 1, 3)('%' +search_term + '%')` should be `func.mid(Item.title.like, 1, 3), ('%' +search_term + '%')`. see if that solves the issue, there may be other things wrong with this code, but typeerror is encountered because the object returned from func.mid(...) is not callable, and `('%' +search_term+'%')` is then treated as function argument

Comment: gives diff error..

Comment: OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "%": syntax error [SQL: u'SELECT items.id AS items_id, items.title AS items_title, items.link AS items_link, items.description AS items_description, items.member_since AS items_member_since, items.last_updated AS items_last_updated, items.click_count AS items_click_count \nFROM items \nWHERE mid(?, ?, ?) AND %tor%\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'] [parameters: (<bound method InstrumentedAttribute.like of <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8721aadf50>>, 1, 3, 10, 0)]

Comment: ahh that may be it..I want the search term to be user input from a form

Comment: Your queries don't match. In your SQLAlchemy query, are you trying to do `MID(title, 1, 3) LIKE '%something%'`?

Comment: Hmm I see your point, I used that example from w3 website.  I want the search similiar to google, the description part.  When you search a word, it returns the word, along with the 50 characters infront of it and 50 characters ahead of it.

Comment: I should delete the example as it was just copied and pasted

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you're missing a comma `,` between the parentheses in

```
func.mid(Item.title.like, 1, 3)('%' +search_term + '%')
```

which makes the 2nd expression in parentheses an argument to the first. That is the source of the exception

```
TypeError: 'Function' object is not callable.
```

But, to generate a `LIKE` operator, try:

```
func.mid(Item.title, 1, 3).like('%' +search_term + '%')
```

This gives you WHERE clause that your python code seems to suggest. *In your code, the `like` is misplaced.*

However, if you wanted to generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT MID(City,1,4) AS ShortCity
FROM Customers;
```

The appropriate sqlalchemy code would be

```
session.query(func.mid(Customer.city, 1, 4).label('ShortCity'))
```

*assuming the model is called `Customer` and has a field named `city`.*

Comment: im a noob, but why session.query over Item.query?  Have I set up my project wrong?

Comment: no, they're both valid, i just _happened_ to write my query using a session explicitly. behind the scenes, sqlalchemy is still creating a session.

Comment: links = Item.query(func.mid(Item.title, 1, 3).like('%' +search_term + '%')).paginate(page, 10, True)

    TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callabl

Comment: links = Item.query.filter(Item.title.like('%' +search_term + '%')).paginate(page, 10, True)

Comment: did you try this: `links = Item.query.filter(func.mid(Item.title, 1, 4).like('%' +search_term + '%')).paginate(page, 10, True)`, your code (two comments back) puts the filter expression as a param to query function.